Link from react-router-dom is not redirecting
Since the button is within a <Link /> Component it shoul redirect to the '/home' page but it is not, its not redirecting anywhere. the function PostLogin is being Called i have confirmed
<Link to='/home' >
    <button onClick={postLogin} className="logForm-submit btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</Link>

This is within my React Component,
The function is as goes,
async function postLogin(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        if(logDet.name === "Login"){
            await axios.post('http://localhost:3000/login', {
                username: $("input[name='username']").val(),
                password: $("input[name='password']").val(),
                 email: $("input[name='email']").val()
            },
                {
                    headers: {
                      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                    }
            })
        } else if(logDet.name === "Register"){
            await axios.post('http://localhost:3000/register', {
                username: $("input[name='username']").val(),
                password: $("input[name='password']").val(),
                 email: $("input[name='email']").val()
            },
                {
                    headers: {
                      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                    }
            })
        }
        console.log('Clicked');

        
    }

I have confirmed the function is being called.
My Routes look like,
    <div>
        <Router>
            <Routes>
                <Route element={<Layout />} >
                    <Route path="/itemEntry" element={<ItemEntryForm />} />
                    <Route path='/' element={<LogForm name="Login" />} />
                    <Route path='/home' element={<Home />} />
                    <Route path='/add/location' element={<LocnCustEntry entry='Location' />} />
                    <Route path='/add/cust' element={<LocnCustEntry entry='Cust' />} />
                    <Route path='/add/product' element={<ProdEntry />} />
                    <Route path='/show/:name' element={<PassDataToShowData />} />
                </Route>
            </Routes>
        </Router>
    </div>

Every one of the routes does have a respective Component.
The  Component is as shown,
import React from "react";

function Home(){

    return (
        <>
            <h1>HOME</h1>
        </>

    );
}

export default Home;

I was expecting a redirect to the '/home' page
